# What is the difference between apt-get and aptitude?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

Can anyone please tell me difference between 1 and 2

1. `sudo apt-get install vlc`
2. `sudo aptitude install vlc`

I tried installing vlc with 1 and it did not work, but with 2 it did. I don't get the difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aptitude` is supposed to be a user level program whereas `apt-get` is supposed to be used by higher level programs. It just turns out `apt-get` is easy to use by users so they just use it instead of using the higher level managers like `aptitude` and `synaptic`.

`aptitude` is more user friendly because it adds a layer of abstraction away from `apt-get`, `apt-cache` etc.., `apt-get` is more user friendly than `dpkg` for the same reason. It's really down to user knowledge and what works best for them. `aptitude` and `apt-get` use the same repositories. Let it be clear that `aptitude` does not itself use `apt-get` `apt-cache` etc.. I merely mean to point out that `aptitude` is a higher level package manager.